# Wordpress Edit Page Not Finishing After Upgrade to PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently upgrade a site from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7. I can edit pages in the admin, but when I click update, it never finishes, but the changes show up on the page itself. This problem doesn't happen if I revert to 5.3. The memory limit is set to 128M, so I have no clue what could be causing this, other than the upgrade from 5.3 to 7. Did something change between the two versions of PHP that could cause this?

Comment: There are a bunch of changes from both versions. If you have access to log files I'd suggest try to investigate there first.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer tools for any messages or errors? How about the server's logs? Sounds more like a database issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Did something change between the two versions of PHP that could cause this?

Short answer: Yes it did.

The changes between PHP 5.3 and 7.0 are huge, including a lot of backward compatibility breaks.

I suggest reading the PHP manual where they discuss these issues for each version:

- [PHP 5.4 BC breaks](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php)
- [PHP 5.5 BC breaks](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php)
- [PHP 5.6 BC breaks](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php)
- [PHP 7.0 BC breaks](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)

If you're doing this upgrade, you need to make certain that the software you're running (ie Wordpress and all the plugins and templates that you've installed) will work in PHP 7.

You would be well advised to take the upgrade in steps. Most of the breaking changes were between 5.3->5.4 and 5.6->7.0, so maybe try upgrading to 5.5 or 5.6 first before attempting the jump to 7.0.

You may also find that with the size of the version jump you're attempting, you might be forced into a staged upgrade anyway -- if you're running older versions of Wordpress and your plugins, there might be intermediate upgrades that you have to make to them as well before you can get to a version that works in PHP 7.

Finally, you may decide to only take your upgrade to 5.6 for the time being, as it will be a lot less challenging. You can complete the move to 7.0 later. This is because the update 5.3 to 5.4 or 5.5 or 5.6 should be fairly safe, as the breaking changes in 5.3->5.4 were a long time ago now and any developer keeping up with the times will have had plenty of time to dealt with them by now. However 7.0 is a much more recent release, so not all code has been updated to work with it yet.

The lesson to learn here is to keep up with version changes as they happen, rather than waiting for years to do a single big-bang upgrade.